# Adding Back button for web page loaded within another web page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an `index.php` with two major sections: the `navbar` and the `main-content`. The `navbar` contains links which will load another webpage to the `main-content` through this `jQuery` code:

```
jQuery('#main-content').load('sampleurl');
```

Some of these web pages contain links to another web page, so I want to add a back button. 
I tried using the `history.back()` and `history.go(-1)`, as well as the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but they don't really work in my case.

How will I add the back button in this situation?

Comment: show us your entire code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep your last viewed page in JavaScript variable or in value of hidden input and then you only need to add button with

```
jQuery('#main-content').load(old_url);
```

You must always update your variable when you load your next page via `jQuery('#main-content').load('sampleurl');`

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: Add hash to Url whenever you load the page; and then you can use `history.back()`

```
$(function(){
  if(window.location.hash === 'sampleurl'){
    jQuery('#main-content').load('sampleurl', function(){
      window.location.hash = 'sampleurl'; //<<-- match with your loaded page;
    });
  }
});
```

good luck !

Comment: `if(window.location.hash = 'sampleurl')` --> `if(window.location.hash === 'sampleurl')`

Comment: @Charlie No problem, just a little typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Try manipulating the javascript location or location.hash

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Of course, you need to be able to turn your URL back into the relevant page content too.

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with both Charlie and Michael's answers, since you are already using jQuery, another option is to include the [jQuery Address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/).

You can implement this idea, by creating a function to read a hash path to load new content. Following this, the content can be navigated by the built-in back + forward buttons.
The only challenge I foresee with this implementation is associating the new content with the hash path.

Good luck!